# How to install USB dongle modem in BackTrack?

Tags: linux, modem, backtrack

I've spent the past 2 days and 1½ hour from the third day trying to figure out how to configure my USB modem to start surfing on the net. And now I give up. Obviously I don't know what I'm doing so I need some help. I'm getting an error when trying to connect with wvdial. Here is the error from the terminal:

```
--> Initializing modem. 
--> Sending: AT + CGDCONT=1, "IP", "bredband.tre.se" 
AT + CGDCONT=1, "IP", "bredband.tre.se" 
OK 
--> Modem initialized. 
--> Cannot get information for serial port. 
--> Initializing modem. 
--> Sending: AT + CGDCONT=1, "IP", "bredband.tre.se" 
AT + CGDCONT=1, "IP", "bredband.tre.se" 
OK 
--> Modem initialized. 
--> Sending: ATDT*99# 
--> Waiting for carrier. ATDT*99# ~[7f]}#@!}!}!} }9}#}%B#}%}(}"}'}"}"}&} } } } }%}&URy,kT~ 
CONNECT 
--> Carrier detected.  Waiting for prompt. 
~[7f]}#@!}!}"} }9}#}%B#}%}(}"}'}"}"}&} } } } }%}&URy,'9~ 
--> PPP negotiation detected. 
--> Starting pppd at Fri Aug 17 19:20:17 2012 
--> Pid of pppd: 10401 
--> Using interface ppp0 
--> pppd: ��B  
--> pppd: ��B  
--> pppd: ��B  
--> pppd: ��B 
--> pppd: ��B  
--> pppd: ��B  
--> pppd: ��B  
--> Disconnecting at Fri Aug 17 19:20:18 2012 
--> The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16) --> man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail. 
--> Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information. 
--> Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 40 seconds
```

And my `wvdial.conf` looks like this:

```
[Dialer Defaults]  
Init1 = AT + CGDCONT=1, "IP", "bredband.tre.se" 
Modem Type = USB Modem 
Phone = *99# 
ISDN = 0 
Username = * 
Password = * 
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0 
Baud = 460800 
Pin = 7702
```

This is the `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1505 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bdb:1902 Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV F3507g v2 Mobile Broadband Module
```

I've changed the wvdial.config several times with no success and if I change Init1 to:

```
Init1 = ATZ  
Init2 = AT + CGDCONT=1, "IP", "bredband.tre.se"
```

I get an error saying `ATZ Error Bad init string`. The USB dongle is a Huawei E372 Mobile Broadband modem. It has a SIM card in it and it requires a PIN number of 4 digits to be able to connect to the internet. I tested it on Ubuntu 12.04 and it works fine but I'm having a really hard time trying to set it up on Backtrack 5 R3.

Image of the modem I'm using:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You obviously want to do it the hardest way possible. If you want easier approaches, check out NetworkManager (you probably did that for Ubuntu 12.04) or even the (3 years unmaintained) umtsmon.

Having said that, you are obviously suffering from a concept known as "ZeroCD", where the device comes up first as a usb CD drive, containing auto-installing drivers for Windows.

You need to switch the device to modem before it can work. There is a tool called [USB modeswitch](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/)

But... In case you wonder what you have been talking to:
/dev/ttyACM0 is very likely the Ericsson device. 
It looks to be yet another 3G modem.

Your pppd log shows too little information to be certain on the errors. 
Try adding `debug debug debug` on the options to pppd.

Comment: Oops, umtsmon is 4 years unmaintained already - time flies...

Comment: i've been going back and forward with this for more than a week now with no succeed. I installed usb-modeswitch correctly but i can't find usb_modeswitch.conf in the file system. Could you tell me how to add debug to the pppd and how to actually see the debug file. Sorry for my "noobness". Thanks

Comment: also i just noticed that my device is not listed on `device_reference.txt` Does that mean that my device is not supported by USB-Modeswitch?

Comment: @madcoderz, I don't recognize your device either. But be aware that there are two devices in your system and the /dev/ttyACM0 is likely not the Huawei one.

Comment: @madcoderz, I've never used wvdial. As far as I can tell, you cannot add 'debug' to wvdial, but you could add it to one of the config files in /etc/ppp - e.g. the 'options' file if it exists. Make sure to specify debug three times - we need all the logging you can get hold of.

Comment: @madcoderz: have you tried looking at dmesg and what it spits out when you insert your Huawei stick? it might give a lot of info on what needs to be done!